# Combine conditional with static class NextJS

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, jsx, tailwind-css

In NextJS I'm trying to apply both a static CSS-class and a conditional class to an element. Separated from each other I can make both work, but when combining them it will result in an unexpected error.

```
# This will work
<span className="font-medium">{message}</span>

# This will work too
<span className={status ? "bg-green-600":"bg-orange-600"}>{message}</span>
```

In Visual Studio the following snippet will give an error `',' expected.ts(1005)`

```
# This (where I'm trying to apply *both* classes to the same element) won't work
<span className={"font-medium" + {status ? "bg-green-600":"bg-orange-600"}}>{message}</span>
```

Ignoring that will give following error:

```
Error: 
  x An object member cannot be declared optional
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a space after font-medium, because it will be interpreted as a single class otherwise

```
<span className={"font-medium " + status ? "bg-green-600":"bg-orange-600"}>{message}</span>
```

And with template literals :

```
<span className={'font-medium ${status ? "bg-green-600" : "bg-orange-600" }'}>{message}</span>
```

(Please note it's `and not ' here)

In this type of cases, dont forget to debug by inspecting the element and checking the classes

Comment: you can also use it with template literal 


<span className={``font-medium ${status ? "bg-green-600" : "bg-orange-600" }``}>{message}</span>

Comment: Yes of course, answer edited. Thanks

Comment: Adding a space won't work. The problem is not so much that the class isn't recognized. I'm getting a syntax error that makes my code unusable.

Comment: Even with the template literal ?

Comment: I had to (as you now did too) remove the brackets and use backticks. It's working now.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use backtick (`)  as an alternative like this

```
<span className=`font-medium ${status ? 'bg-green-600' : 'bg-orange-600' `}>{message}</span>
```

Comment: That indeed seemed to work.